# Pushing UIViewController onto a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

The other day I asked about using a [UINavigationController as a child of a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566887/uinavigationcontroller-as-child-view-of-uiviewcontroller).  I got that working via the answer.  Now what I'm trying to do is push a controller onto the nav stack.  When a table cell is touched, I do the following:

```
- (void) showSetup {
    NSLog(@"Showing Setup");
    SetupViewController *controller = [[SetupViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SetupViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.setupViewController = controller;
    self.setupViewController.title = @"Setup";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.setupViewController animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

I can see the log statement in my console, but the view never changes.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked if self.navigationController is nil?

Comment: I just did that and it is *not* nil.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a setupViewController property?

Comment: @hipplar - that's not the problem.  I have no good reason for it other than examples I used from books do it this way.  However, I changed it and I still get the same results.

Comment: Have you checked that controller is non-nil? If it *is* nil, then check your SetupViewController -initWithNibName: and make sure that it is returning properly.

Comment: @Gregg: Are you sure ViewController, where you have the Tableview, is already inside a NavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, well it's a bit tricky without knowing the details of your implementation -- I assumed that you implemented your navigation controller as in the linked article.  Also although you give no details it sounds like you've added a table view controller somewhere along the line, so I made the UIViewController conform to the UITableView protocols to handle everything in one place:

`@interface SOViewController : UIViewController`<`UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource > {`

```
  UINavigationController* navController;
}

- (IBAction) pushMe:(id)sender;
@end
```

I dropped a button on the SOViewController's view in IB and wired the pushMe: action to it.  I also created another UIViewController-based class called `JunkController` and dropped a "Junk" label on it's view in IB -- that's all I did in IB.  In the SOViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] init] retain];
navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
navController.toolbarHidden = YES;

UITableViewController* tvController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
UITableView* tv = [[UITableView alloc] init];
tvController.tableView = tv;
tv.delegate = self;
tv.dataSource = self;
[navController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tvController]];
```

In the pushMe: action implementation:

`[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];`

Implemented the tableView delegate and datasource methods; for selection:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  { 
    NSLog(@"row selected");
    JunkController* junk = [[JunkController alloc] initWithNibName:@"junkcontroller" bundle:nil];
    [navController pushViewController:junk animated:YES];
    [junk release];
}
```

This should yield an app that surfaces a screen with a "Push me" button.  When that button is pressed you should get an animated modal navigation-based table view -- mine had one row in it that contained a label "select me".  Touching this row should animate the junk controller into view.

Comment: yar it was about a 10 minute code job -- primary purpose was to demonstrate the full traverse of what the OP wanted :)

Comment: No worries just trying to help this guy out.  +'ed

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make setupViewController a declared property in this view controller.  Also, I could be mistaken but I thought "controller" was a reserved name in Cocoa, I'd change that name.  So make sure you have registered with the UITableViewDelegate and use `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to hook into and push your new view controller as follows:

```
SetupViewController *detailViewController = [[SetupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SetupViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.title = @"Setup";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

Goodluck!

Comment: As far as the delegate stuff goes, read my post again.  I'm already doing that. I'm getting the log statement from my method when I click on the table cell row.  I've debugged, and the code goes all the way through, no errors.  It just doesn't navigate.

Comment: 'controller' is not a reserved word. I have used it without incident. And Xcode does not colorize it as a reserved word.

Comment: pushViewController will push the new view, so either there is something wrong with SetupViewController, or you navigationController hasn't been setup properly.